# Action Items with dropdown menu view

Tags: android, menu, menuitem, actionview

I want to create something similar to this picture where you select the action view and it brings up a dropdown list of items, is that just a submenu of the menu item or something else?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is probably to bundle in the GreenDroid library and use their solution: https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid

Although this could also be accomplished with a basic LinearLayout containing a few buttons.

Comment: so I take it that what is shown in the picture I posted is just something only implemented in the `ShareActionProvider` and not something that is part of the SDK? I suppose I could just implement a `ContextMenu`

Comment: It can definitely be done with the regular SDK, but as you said, not without writing your own support code.

Answer (score 0):

My guess id that you could do it with a new activity with the options. Normal dialogues are created this way. Then use the adequate layout to make it look like this. You can get the sources for the Option dialogue from the android source code and then style it accordingly.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's looks like just a `Spinner` as `ActionView` with it's own adapter.